Is it safe to use a subquery as a source table for a merge statement?
I found some similar questions but none exactly matching my use case.
When trying to use a MERGE statement Microsoft mentions the following:
Source

It's important to specify only the columns from the target table to use for matching purposes. That is, specify columns from the target table that are compared to the corresponding column of the source table. Don't attempt to improve query performance by filtering out rows in the target table in the ON clause; for example, such as specifying AND NOT target_table.column_x = value. Doing so can return unexpected and incorrect results.

In another place it mentions that you could use views to "filter" the source table.
Source

Define a view on the source or target that returns the filtered rows and reference the view as the source or target table. If the view is defined on the target table, any actions against it must satisfy the conditions for updating views. For more information about updating data by using a view, see Modifying Data Through a View.

But what I cannot find is whether or not you can "safely" use a subquery instead of the source table.
For example:
MERGE TableA a
USING (
    SELECT *
    FROM TableB b
    WHERE
        b.Status = 5

) b
ON a.ID = b.ForeignID
... MATCH statements ...

Would this cause similar problems as using a CTE or filtering by using the ON statement?

"cause similar problems as using a CTE" - what "similar problems" are you referring to? T-SQL's MERGE is designed to be used with CTEs, including using a CTE as the source and as the target of a MERGE.

Some recommended reading, if you do "want" to use MERGE: So, you want to use MERGE, eh?

...that said, the only hard-and-fast rule I've internalized for MERGE is to use HOLDLOCK.

@Dai I'm not sure what problems, it is mentioned in the second source I provided.
Use the WITH  clause to filter out rows from the source or target tables. This method is similar to specifying additional search criteria in the ON clause and may produce incorrect results. We recommend that you avoid using this method or test thoroughly before implementing it.

@Sotem The second article you linked-to was last-updated 2012 and was written for SQL Server 2008 - which is long dead now and SQL Server has changed a lot since then. I'd ignore that article and follow current-advice instead (see ThomA's links).

@Dai I've seen the views issue mentioned elsewhere as well.
In the more recent documentation I don't find CTE mentioned at all, but this could simply be an oversight.
So I'm not that sure about using or not using the CTE.
That said, it isn't relevant to the question but thanks for pointing it out.

@Sotem In my experience, Updatable-Views are controversial not because of any of their inherent qualities, but because there's too many people out there who honestly-just-don't-know-what-they-are-doing and they'll push out an Updatable-VIEW that does RBAR DML which they think works just fine with their test workloads but will either make the DB keel-over during load or worse: silently drop data (because they incorrectly assumed DML is always single-row) - Other than that, I'm unconcerned about VIEWs, CTEs, etc.

These two methods are exactly the same. A view and a CTE and a derived table (what you are calling a subquery) and an inline TVF behave identically to the compiler: they are inlined into the query.
The documentation is actually incorrect (note I've linked the latest docs):

Use the WITH <common table expression> clause to filter out rows from the source or target tables. This method is similar to specifying additional search criteria in the ON clause and may produce incorrect results. We recommend that you avoid using this method or test thoroughly before implementing it.

This is completely false as I will explain.
MERGE functions like a FULL JOIN. The source and target are full-joined together, and the ON condition in the MERGE is the ON condition of the FULL JOIN. Then the WHEN MATCHED AND conditions go in a later filter like a WHERE. Sometimes the FULL JOIN becomes a LEFT or INNER if the match clauses are not present.
So for example, the following
MERGE TableA a
USING (
    SELECT *
    FROM TableB b
    WHERE
        b.Status = 5
) b
ON a.ID = b.ForeignID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (...)
  VALUES (...)
WHEN MATCHED AND a.x <> b.x THEN
  UPDATE SET
    x = b.x;
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  DELETE;

becomes pseudo-code like:
SELECT  -- data to MERGE
  a.ID,
  b.ForeignID,
  b.x,
  CASE WHEN b.ForeignID IS NULL THEN 'INSERT'
       WHEN b.ForeignID IS NOT NULL AND a.x <> b.x THEN 'UPDATE'
       WHEN a.ID IS NULL THEN 'DELETE'
    END AS $action
FROM TableA a
FULL JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM TableB b
    WHERE
        b.Status = 5
) b
ON a.ID = b.ForeignID
WHERE (b.ForeignID IS NULL)  -- not matched
   OR (a.ID IS NOT NULL AND b.ForeignID IS NOT NULL AND a.x <> b.x) -- matched AND
   OR (a.ID IS NULL)  -- not matched by source
;

As you can see, it would make no difference where the source or target come from, whether a table, view, derived table or iTVF.
The key here is: if you want to merge to and from a subset of the data, then filter the source and target before you get to the ON. The ON clause should only be used for one thing: matching up rows. Do not put any other conditions in there.

"The documentation is actually incorrect" - do you have suggestions on how to make it correct? And by "suggestions", I mean a pull request against the docs.

Can you generate and share the query-plans that you get with different CTEs/filtering approaches?

@BenThul Good idea, you should make a pull request. I don't know, something like "This method is similar to using a view, and any actions against it must satisfy the conditions for updating views."

@Dai Almost identical https://dbfiddle.uk/DXm953dp but you can see what happens if you try using the ON the results are incorrect

@Charlieface - why me? It's not that I'm against doing it (I've done it in the past), but it's not my work/suggestion; it's yours. The more people willing/able to contribute to the docs, the better they get for everyone. Unless you're somehow prohibited from doing so, it should be you. Here's a link to the source.
