MERGE runs WHEN NOT MATCHED clause unexpectedly
I'm running a MERGE statement in SQL Server where the source table has a single row with a requestMaterialId that matches with a row in the target table. My expectation is that the WHEN MATCHED clause should run, and the WHEN NOT MATCHED clause should be ignored because the requestMaterialId in the source matches the id in the target.
Here's what I observed:
When I remove the WHEN NOT MATCHED clause, the WHEN MATCHED clause executes as expected.
However, when I include the WHEN NOT MATCHED clause, SQL Server tries to execute it and attempts to insert a new row in the target table, which I did not expect since there should already be a match.
I’ve double-checked that:

Both source and target have the same requestMaterialId (4632).

The data types for requestMaterialId and id match between source and target.

The source query only returns one row.


Why is SQL Server trying to execute the WHEN NOT MATCHED clause? Could there be something I’m missing about how the MERGE statement determines matches?
Table source which is the product of an aggregate function indeed:

This is the MERGE query:
    MERGE INTO [tblRequestMaterial] AS target
USING (
  SELECT
    t1.requestMaterialId,  
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.novaFieldName = 'productHierarchyId' THEN t1.pushValue END) AS productHierarchyId
  FROM tblChange t1
  WHERE t1.novaTableName = '[nd].[tblRequestMaterial]'
    AND t1.requestMaterialId IN (
      SELECT fc.requestMaterialId
      FROM FieldCombinations fc
      WHERE fc.fieldCombination = 'productHierarchyId'
    )
  GROUP BY t1.requestMaterialId
) AS source
ON target.id = source.requestMaterialId

WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET [productHierarchyId] = source.productHierarchyId
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (id, [productHierarchyId])
  VALUES (source.requestMaterialId, source.productHierarchyId);

Update:
I just created a sample of all tables. MERGE works as expected in this case and now I am thinking what can cause the original code not working properly. All I can add at this point is that FieldCombinations is a temporary table in my original code which is created through a dynamic SQL run. Also, the MERGE query itself is created by dynamic sql and is run later as this is only one iteration of a larger loop
https://dbfiddle.uk/GCr9QfXv
Update 2:
This is the error I am getting when I am running the original query:

Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table
'tblRequestMaterial' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.


Please create for us a [mre] ideally a SQL DBFiddle so we can see it in operation. Long story short though, there will be something wrong with your matching, because while merge does have some issues, this isn't one of them

But maybe this is relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78838042/is-it-safe-to-use-a-subquery-as-a-source-table-for-a-merge-statement

Given the cast-as-ints, what are the actual data types of tblRequestMaterial.id and myTable.requestMaterialId?

@AlwaysLearning they are both INT, I did that based on the recommendation of ChatGPT to make sure the data type is not the issue for matching. Even if I remove the CAST function the result is the same

Unnecessary casts can cause performance issues

Not sure why anyone trusts ChatGPT given it's technical faults are well known

Add output $action, inserted.*,deleted.* so you can see what happens, but whatever you see doesn't happen, probably there's another row tricking you out

@DaleK I created some sample data and added an update to the question

Well given the complex factors involved, I suggest you are the only person who can solve the problem, using classic debugging techniques of slowly building the solution up until it fails. As for your last posted error - that is surely self explanatory?

@DaleK at this point I am certain the dynamic sql or temp table are not the culprit because I am getting the same error with the regular tables too. It seems the culprit is IDENTITY function in the id column. MERGE does not like it from the get go

Have you set identity insert on, as is required to address that issue?

But anyway you already said you are only ever updating a row... so that doesn't care about identity insert, having that error implies that merge is trying to insert a new row.

This sounds vaguely familiar. I think it's a known MERGE bug. What does: SELECT @@VERSION returns? And is: id an identity in tblRequestMaterial?

@siggemannen yes, id is an IDENTITY field in tblRequestMaterial

@DaleK I have not changed anything in the IDENTITY field and I am not planning to do it too, I have changed my main query and it seems it is working just fine now, I will post an answer once I am confident it is working


...when I include the WHEN NOT MATCHED clause, SQL Server tries to execute it and attempts to insert a new row in the target table, which I did not expect since there should already be a match.

MATCHED and NOT MATCHED does not exclude each other - there are (or could be) matching and non matching rows ...
See the sample below
--      Sample    Data:  
Create Table tbl_target (id Int, txt Text);
Insert Into tbl_target VALUES( 1, 'Text 1' ), ( 2, 'Text 2' );
Select * From tbl_target;




id
txt




1
Text 1


2
Text 2



--      Merge:  
Merge Into tbl_target t
Using
  ( Select 1 as ID, 'Updated 1' as txt Union All
    Select 2, 'Updated 2' Union All
    Select 3, 'Inserted 3' Union All
    Select 4, 'Inserted 4' ) x ON(x.ID = t.ID)
When Matched Then UPDATE SET t.txt = x.txt
When Not Matched Then INSERT VALUES(x.id, x.txt);

--      check the result
Select * From tbl_target;

Result:



id
txt




1
Updated 1


2
Updated 2


3
Inserted 3


4
Inserted 4



fiddle

OP has suggested that there is only a single row in the source table, which matches a row in the target table. There are no other rows to not match (apparently anyway).

@DaleK OP has at least two rows in using sql otherwise there will be no NOT MATCHED rows for the attempted insert....

That's exactly why they have asked the question, it shouldn't happen but they claim it is. But we need a MRE in order to  assist.

@DaleK Agreed, that shouldn't happen. I'd say that there has to be explanation and usualy that is the most simple one - there is one row in using sql that is a match and there is at least one more row that isn't.... In my opinion OP thinks that MATCH should exclude NOT MATCH as in the quated text.

Turns out that MERGE does not like IDENTITY in column id even though it may not be executed so I had to remove the block. If the block is really required another option is removing IDENTITY from the id column.
